# Pandas- datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Hola buenas tardes!!. Mi consulta es la siguiente. Tengo una serie de datos que importé desde Excel (forma parte de un DataFrame). Así luce la misma:

```
0      2021-05-03 00:00:00
1      2021-08-01 00:00:00
2      2021-08-01 00:00:00
3      2021-08-09 00:00:00
4      2021-08-01 00:00:00
              ...         
128    2021-11-01 00:00:00
129    2021-03-01 00:00:00
130    2021-07-12 00:00:00
131    2021-08-02 00:00:00
132    2021-09-06 00:00:00
Name: fecha_inicio, Length: 133, dtype: object
```

El objetivo final es pasar el DataFrame a formato "json". Entonces lo siguiente que hago es pasar la columna de "object" a "datetime":

```
df.fecha_inicio = pd.to_datetime(df.fecha_inicio, format = "%Y-%m-%d", errors = 'coerce')
```

```
0     2021-05-03
1     2021-08-01
2     2021-08-01
3     2021-08-09
4     2021-08-01
         ...    
128   2021-11-01
129   2021-03-01
130   2021-07-12
131   2021-08-02
132   2021-09-06
Name: fecha_inicio, Length: 133, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Y finalmente lo paso a un archivo .json:

```
df.to_json("ejemplo.json", orient = 'columns')
```

Ahora, el problema que tengo es que los datos que pase a "datetime" se ven así:

```
"fecha_inicio":{"0":1620000000000,"1":1627776000000,"2":1627776000000,"3":1628467200000,"4":1627776000000,"5":1621209600000,"6":1626048000000,"7":1625097600000,"8":1625097600000,"9":1627862400000,"10":1629244800000,"11":1630454400000,"12":1622505600000,"13":1630454400000,"14":1630454400000,"15":1623888000000,"16":1630454400000,"17":1625097600000,"18":1629072000000,"19":1630454400000,"20":1627862400000,"21":1627862400000,"22":1627862400000,"23":1624838400000,"24":1626652800000,"25":1625097600000,"26":1625097600000,"27":1635724800000,"28":1627776000000,"29":1630454400000,"30":1630454400000,"31":1630886400000,"32":1630454400000,"33":1630454400000,"34":1630454400000,"35":1635724800000,"36":1622505600000,"37":1633046400000,"38":1622505600000,"39":1630454400000,"40":1627776000000,"41":1630454400000,"42":1627862400000,"43":1627776000000,"44":1624924800000,"45":1626739200000,"46":1627862400000,"47":1625097600000,"48":1630454400000,"49":1617148800000,"50":1630454400000,"51":1627776000000,"52":1630886400000,"53":1633046400000,"54":1625097600000,"55":1627862400000,"56":1625097600000,"57":1627776000000,"58":1627776000000,"59":1629417600000,"60":1619827200000,"61":null,"62":null,"63":1628899200000,"64":1630281600000,"65":1631664000000,"66":1621209600000,"67":1631577600000,"68":1627430400000,"69":1622505600000,"70":1625097600000,"71":1630454400000,"72":1625097600000,"73":1633046400000,"74":1633046400000,"75":1620000000000,"76":1630454400000,"77":1630454400000,"78":1630454400000,"79":1630454400000,"80":1625443200000,"81":1627862400000,"82":1629072000000,"83":1630454400000,"84":1633046400000,"85":1625097600000,"86":1636934400000,"87":1636934400000,"88":1635724800000,"89":1636934400000,"90":1630454400000,"91":1630454400000,"92":1622419200000,"93":1620000000000,"94":1627689600000,"95":1625097600000,"96":1630454400000,"97":1630454400000,"98":1661990400000,"99":1622419200000,"100":1619740800000,"101":1630454400000,"102":1630454400000,"103":1630454400000,"104":1622505600000,"105":null,"106":1617926400000,"107":1627776000000,"108":1630454400000,"109":1628467200000,"110":1630454400000,"111":1627776000000,"112":1627776000000,"113":1625097600000,"114":1630540800000,"115":1633046400000,"116":1630454400000,"117":1631577600000,"118":1630454400000,"119":1631664000000,"120":1631232000000,"121":1625097600000,"122":1622851200000,"123":1630454400000,"124":1619827200000,"125":1627257600000,"126":1626048000000,"127":1627862400000,"128":1635724800000,"129":1614556800000,"130":1626048000000,"131":1627862400000,"132":1630886400000}
```

O sea, en vez de verse las fechas se ven esos números. Alguien sabe que son? o por que pasa?. Desde ya muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más simple y más consistente cuando uno trabaja con un formato `json` es trabajar con el formato `ISO` de fechas. [`to_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html?highlight=to_json#pandas.DataFrame.to_json) permite generar las fechas en este formato desde un `datetime` sin problemas, pero en el caso de `orient = 'columns'` el formato por defecto es el de `epoch` por lo que debes especificarlo:

```
df.to_json(orient='columns', date_format='iso')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! ahí va perfecto

Answer (score 1):

Esto ocurre por que los datos de la columna es de tipo Timestamp, lo que puedes hacer es convertirlos a string. Pandas infiere el tipo de dato y esto podría complicar un poco las cosas, en caso pandas haya inferido el tipo de dato entonces deberemos de aplicar la conversión.

```py
from datetime import datetime

df.fecha_inicio = df.fecha_inicio.apply(lambda x: datetime.strftime(x,"%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Una vez hecho esto ya podemos transformarlo a JSON sin problemas.

```py
df.to_json("ejemplo.json", orient = 'columns')
```

Sin embargo, si pandas no infiere el tipo de dato entonces debemos de aplicar la conversión a un formato de fecha, como lo sería Timestamp, esto por que no queremos toda la fecha `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS`, solo queremos el formato `yyyy-mmm-dd`.

```py
df.fecha_inicio = pd.to_datetime(df.fecha_inicio, format = "%Y-%m-%d", errors = 'coerce')
df.fecha_inicio = df.fecha_inicio.apply(lambda x: datetime.strftime(x,"%Y-%m-%d"))

#convertimos a json
df.to_json("ejemplo.json", orient = 'columns')
```

Y con esto ya tendríamos nuestro JSON de forma correcta.

```json
{"fecha_inicio":{"0":"2021-05-03","1":"2021-08-01","2":"2021-08-01","3":"2021-08-09","4":"2021-08-01",...}}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!